# Classify data using training set with weights for classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-mining, text-classification

I have a dataset with 3 variables:

```
job title (classes) , task (text), task importance (0-100)
```

There are 900 jobs in the data, each has several rows of tasks, and tasks are weighted based on their relevance to the job (0-100). Tasks can be common among some jobs.

I also have another dataset that has the following variables:

```
id, job description (text)
```

In the second dataset each person explained their job description.
I want to use the first dataset as the training data to predict job titles of the jobs in the second data set.

I want to use scikit learn. My main questions are how to incorporate the weight of classes in the training dataset and what is the best model to use for this dataset to predict the probability of classes in the second dataset?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pre-process your training dataset and extract features (e.g., you can use simple bag of words, unigram, bigram, tf-idf or more complex features with `NLP`) from the tasks texts after tokenizing the texts (you can use standard text mining techniques such as removing stop words, stemming etc.). For example a sample row in the training dataset may look like the following if you use simple BOW features:

```
word1 word2 ... wordn jobtitle
  3     0         1   XXXXXX
```

Here the features are the words that appear in the task texts and the counts reflect the number of occurrences, each row corresponds to a single jobtitle.

Now, train a classifier on this dataset (e.g., Naive Bayes, SVM, RandomForest, Boosting, Multinomial Logit, Decision Tree etc.), you need to try several of them (by testing their performance on a held-out validation dataset) to see which one works best for your validation dataset.

The classifier learns a function `f` that approximates `jobtitle=f(word1, word2,...,wordn)`.

Next, to use your classifier for prediction on the test dataset, you need to again preprocess the data to transform it into a structure exactly same as your training dataset. This time you need to tokenize and extract features from your job description. A sample test dataset may look like the following:

```
  word1 word2 ... wordn 
      1     2         0
```

Here the features are the same words that appear in the training dataset, now the counts will be the number of occurrences in the job descriptions in the test dataset. Now you can ask your trained classifier to predict the jobtitle for each row in your test dataset and associated probability with the function `f` learnt from the training dataset.

Comment: Dear Sandipan, Thanks for the response. I can follow these steps when I have dataset with only texts and classes and no weights. But, I have weights for each line of data.

For example,  here is one part of my data:
Job title  task                          relevance
Sales Estimate or quote prices 70
Sales Sign contracts 50
Sales Talk with customers 90


I guess I need to create one bag of words for “Sales” jobs but I want to incorporate the relevance of each task too.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Oh actually you need to then associate the weights from each task with the word features obtained from the task. For example, for the task sales, if you construct the bigram feature 'quote prices' then you can directly assign the weight 0.7 as value of that feature and similarly for other features and learn the classifier. Now on the test dataset from the description text you can also find some sort of weight for the same  feature (e.g. relative frequency or tf-idf weight) and use the classifier to predict.

Comment: So, that's what I don't know how to do. I used the following code for the vectorizer.

vect = CountVectorizer( max_df=0.8, min_df=1,
        ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
I looked at countvectorizer parameters and none of them look related to weight. Do you know how I should set it up? Thanks